# How bad is it to do file operation every second?

Tags: c#, timer, file-read

I am working on a Windows Form Application in C# using Visual Studio 2008, and I currently have two forms `MainForm` and `TimeSettingForm`. `MainForm` is always open, while `TimeSettingForm` only opens when the user clicks a `Button` on `MainForm`.

My program needs an event method, which only occurs **once at a certain time every day** and the user can choose that time on `TimeSettingForm`. Since `TimeSettingForm` is usually closed and the set time needs to be not affected by re-opening `MainForm`, I have a method in `TimeSettingForm` that saves the set time in `.txt` file. The time can be selected by using `DateTimePicker`'s time portion only.

Now, I have a `Timer` control that runs every second, and it constantly reads from the `.txt` file to retrieve the set time for the event, because the time can easily get changed on `TimeSettingForm`, rather than a fixed time.

```
/*Timer control that runs every second */
private void TimerForEvent_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string eventTime;
    string fileName = GetFileName(); //Get the .txt file name here
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        //Read line
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            //Event time is in format of "HH:mm"
            eventTime = sr.ReadLine();
        }

        //Separate into hour and minute portion   
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(eventTime);
        int eventHour = dt.Hour;
        int eventMinute = dt.Minute;

        //Check if the current time matches the eventTime
        DateTime DTnow = DateTime.Now;
        if(DTnow.Hour == eventHour && DTnow.Minute == eventMinute && DTnow.Second == "0")
        {
            //The event happens
        }
    }
    else
    {
        eventTime = "Time Not Set"; 
    }
}
```

However, this seems very inefficient because not only does it keep checking if the current time is the same as the set time, but also it keeps reading from the `.txt` file **every second**. Is there any better way to achieve this? 
I would also like to know how bad of a practice it is to constantly read data from a file.

Comment: Why not use a `FileSystemWatcher`? Every second is pretty inefficient but you're not doing much apart from calling `File.Exists()` so the end result won't impact the machine all that much. Still better to increase the time interval at the very least

Comment: Perfect use-case for a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Why not keep the value in MainForm? An event or form close sets it so there’s no need to monitor a file for such a simple thing.

Comment: Very Inefficient. Perfect use case for FileSystemWatcher

Comment: Thanks everyone. I had never heard of `FileSystemWatcher`. I will try that! Thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking file each second is OK from OS performance perspective. There is caching and such involved which makes it very resource efficient.
However, IMHO, there are better practices to achieve your goal.

You are solving two problems:

a) application/user settings persistence - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings

b) event scheduling - how to schedule an event at the specific time.

As for b) one common approach is to compute (at program start, setting change and at event execution) how much time is left to next event occurrence and set `TimerForEvent.Interval` accordingly.

Your current solution or event scheduling is not very robust as it is not guaranteed that timer event will be executed exactly one per second. Windows is not real-time OS and timer execution could be blocked for several seconds which could result in missing tick at particular execution time second.